# Why is $Br(K_s\rightarrow l+\nu_l+\pi)$ so small?

Tags: particle-physics

I am looking at the decay of the $K_S$ meson and according to the [particle data group](http://www-pdg.lbl.gov/2016/listings/rpp2016-list-K-zero-S.pdf) we have the following branching ratios:
\begin{align}
Br(K_S\rightarrow \pi^0\pi^0)&=30.69\%\\
Br(K_S\rightarrow \pi^+\pi^-)&=69.20\%\\
Br(K_S\rightarrow \pi^\pm e^\mp \nu_e)&=7.04\times 10^{-4}
\end{align}
I cannot find (anywhere) an explanation for the large difference between these two values. From what I can tell both the 1, 2 and 3 diagrams involve one weak interaction which is Cabibbo suppressed at one of its vertexes. Which would indicate a branching ratio of the same order for the three reactions. My question is therefore what factor is suppressing the semi-leptonic $K_S$ decay?

Comment: Hint: $\mathcal{B}(K_L \to \pi^\pm e^\mp \nu_e) = 40.55 \%$

Comment: @dukwon I am aware of this, I am however particularly intrested in the reason why $K_S$ does not decay into these. As far as I am aware even though the branching ratio of $\mathcal{B}(K_L \to \pi^\pm e^\mp \nu_e)\gt\gt \mathcal{B}(K_S \to \pi^\pm e^\mp \nu_e)$ the transition rates are almost the same. Hence this doesn't really answer why the semileptonic decay is much less probable then the hadronic.

Comment: this may help http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/~thomson/lectures/partIIIparticles/Handout12_2009.pdf .

Comment: "Leptonic decays are more likely for the K-long because the three pion decay modes have a lower decay rate than the two pion modes of the K-short"  page 10 of PDF.  415 of book

Comment: @annav Hi, thanks for your comments. My question is more directed towards $K_S$ and why its hadronic decays are more probable then its leptonic decays (irrespective of the decays of $K_L$).